# Apache Sentry with Impala - Roles assigned to Groups in LDAP won't reflect

Tags: ldap, impala, apache-sentry

We do not use CDH stack as such but installed Impala, Sentry standalone.

Hadoop core-site.xml has CompositeGroupsMapping with ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping and LdapGroupsMapping.
Impala is configured with Apache Sentry and LDAP.

Any roles assigned to LDAP Groups does not reflect for the user but roles assigned to Unix Groups do reflect.

Apache Sentry 2.1.0-cdh6.1.0

Comment: I don't understand the question? You should be usng LdapGroupMapping if you want it to recognize your LDAP groups. Shell based is local to the Linux machines, i.e., users and groups

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Impala needs Hadoop Config, because it is Impala that gets the Groups of the User and not Sentry.